# Loading Vue component based on (changeable) variable

Tags: vue.js, components

total newbie with Vue.js here, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

I want to load components based on the content of a variable - so if the content of my variable changes, I want the component to change accordingly. I have all components imported (e.g. `import Project1 from "@/components/Project1";`), which again is saved in  `components: {'p1': Project1}`

I use `<component :is="this.goTo.page"/>`
with goTo.page being defined in data as `data() {return {goTo: {page: "p1"}}}`.
The problem seems to be the reactivness of goTo.page. I update it via `this.$set(this.goTo, "page", "p2");`. When running, i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined`, which I honestly don't understand, since its initialized with "p1".

```js
import * as Matter from "matter-js";
import Project1 from "@/components/Project1";
import Project2 from "@/components/Project2";
import Project3 from "@/components/Project3";

export default {
  name: "Work",
  components: {
    'p1': Project1,
    'p2': Project2,
    'p3': Project3
  },
  data() {
    return {
      goTo: {
        page: "p1"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startMatter: function () {
  let harrie = require('@/assets/img/harrie.png');
  let kub = require('@/assets/img/kub.png');
  let jacs = require('@/assets/img/jacs.png');

  let container = document.getElementById('threecontainerWork');
  let nameTag = document.getElementById("title");

  let width = container.offsetWidth;
  let height = container.offsetHeight;

  let engine = Matter.Engine.create({});

  let renderer = Matter.Render.create({
    element: document.getElementById('matterContainer'),
    canvas: container,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      wireframes: false
    }
  })

  let borderLeft = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, 1, height * 2, {isStatic: true});
  let borderRight = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(width, 0, 1, height * 2, {isStatic: true});
  let roof = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(container.getBoundingClientRect().left, 0, width * 2, 1, {isStatic: true});
  let ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(container.getBoundingClientRect().left, height, width * 2, 1, {isStatic: true});
  let collider = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(container.offsetWidth / 2, container.offsetHeight, nameTag.offsetWidth, 1, {
    isStatic: true,
    isSensor: true,
    render: {
      fillStyle: 'red'
    }
  });

  let nameTagBox = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(container.offsetWidth / 2, container.offsetHeight / 2, nameTag.offsetWidth, nameTag.offsetHeight, {isStatic: true});

  let project1 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(container.offsetWidth / 2, 100, 200, 200, {
    render: {
      sprite: {
        texture: harrie
      }
    }
  });
  let project2 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(201, 0, 200, 200, {
    render: {
      sprite: {
        texture: kub
      }
    }
  });
  let project3 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(1400, 0, 200, 200, {
    render: {
      sprite: {
        texture: jacs
      }
    }
  });

  let polyStack = Matter.Composites.stack(container.offsetWidth / 2, 50, 2, 10, 0, 0, function (x, y) {
    let sides = Math.round(Matter.Common.random(2, 8));
    return Matter.Bodies.polygon(x, y, sides, Matter.Common.random(100, 100));
  })

  let mouse = Matter.Mouse.create(renderer.canvas);
  let mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse
  })


  let colStart = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function (event) {
    var pairs = event.pairs;

    for (var i = 0, j = pairs.length; i != j; ++i) {
      var pair = pairs[i];

      if (pair.bodyA === collider) {
        switch (pair.bodyB.id) {
          case project1.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p1");
            break;
          case project2.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p2");
            break;
          case project3.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p3");
            break;
        }
      } else if (pair.bodyB === collider) {
        switch (pair.bodyA.id) {
          case project1.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p1");
            break;
          case project2.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p2");
            break;
          case project3.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p3");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  let colEnd = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionEnd', function (event) {
    var pairs = event.pairs;

    for (var i = 0, j = pairs.length; i != j; ++i) {
      var pair = pairs[i];

      if (pair.bodyA === collider) {
        switch (pair.bodyB.id) {
          case project1.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
          case project2.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
          case project3.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
        }
      } else if (pair.bodyB === collider) {
        switch (pair.bodyA.id) {
          case project1.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
          case project2.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
          case project3.id:
            this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "noview");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  });


  // TODO implement Vue.set(this.goTo, 'page', "p2"); correctly -> Matter Hell

  Matter.World.add(engine.world, [ground, borderLeft, borderRight, roof, collider, project1, project2, project3, nameTagBox, polyStack, mouseConstraint, colStart, colEnd]);
  Matter.Engine.run(engine);
  Matter.Render.run(renderer);

}
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.startMatter();
    })
  }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#upperDiv {
    position: relative;

    width: 98vw;
    height: 81vh;
    margin: auto auto 1vh auto;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    top: 9vh /*Für alle anderen auch*/
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 2vh 3vw;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    background-color: #1d1c1c;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.threeContainer {
    width: 96vw;
    height: 70vh;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="upperDiv">
      <div class="threeContainer" id="matterContainer">
        <canvas id="threecontainerWork" class="threeContainer"></canvas>
      </div>
      <p id="title">My work</p>
    </div>
    <component :is="goTo.page"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<component :is="goTo.page"/>`

`this` is not available in `<template>`. Everything "inside" `this`, is available.

In addition to the above and per your update,

```js
methods: {
  startMatter: function () {
    //some matter.js
    //if body collision detected:
    this.$set(this.goTo, 'page', "p2");
  },
},
```

The second argument of this.$set should be a string with the key name you wish to update.

If that doesn't work, your nextTick might be the problem.  As in, there is no nextTick after mounted, unless something is updated.

```js
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.startMatter();
  })
}
```

Updated based on comments.

I believe that it's this line (line 108?), which overrides your `this`.

`let colStart = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function (event) {`

Try instead:
`let colStart = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {`

Function has it own scope /this. Vue normally binds to it, however I think that doesn't work as you're in matters callback now. The arrow function ensures the scope is lexical.

Same goes for:
`let colEnd = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionEnd', function (event) {`,
change it to:
`let colEnd = Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionEnd', (event) => {`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but that didn't change anything. I attached a larger part of my code. In case that helps

Comment: Hi! Again, thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it didnt solve it and i figured it has something to do with my matter.js code. So i will probably have to create a new post in the matter.js forum. But again, thank you for your help!

Comment: In the code you've posted you are not doing anything with matter.js?

Comment: Yes, i included the whole matter code now. To explain it shortly: depending on the two rectangles colliding, i want to dynamically load the respective component associated with the rectangle. With some tweaking I am now stuck with `Work.vue?46ca:117 Uncaught TypeError: this.$set is not a function` which I assume means that ive lost the reference of "this" at some point

Comment: Updated answer per your last comment

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it!